# Checking installed files in OpenSUSE

Tags: package-management, opensuse

How to check what files are installed by an installed package under OpenSUSE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For installed packages, there is a "Files" tab within the Software Management element of YAST, which lists what files were installed.

From the command line `rpm -ql foo` (as root? some rootish programs allow a normal user to query stuff) should list the files from package foo, again only if it is installed.

Comment: If you know a file, but not the package, you can use `-f` to identify by path of a file, e.g. `rpm -qilf /etc/passwd` (the `-i` includes information about the package -- name, version, install date, etc)